# Can I determine what is causing my unpackaged workbook to increase in size?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have two versions of a workbook. The packaged versions are just around 4MB each. When I unpackage them, one is reduced to around 2MB, and the other increases to about 50MB. There are two additional tables in the larger, but there is not enough data in those tables to cause such a spike. Is there a way to identify what is causing this increase in size? I need to run this workbook through an analyzer, but the one I am using won't accept a workbook of this size. Alternatively, if that is not possible, is there an analyzer tool that can accept this size workbook? I am using this one at the moment: https://paulisdataviz.shinyapps.io/tableau_workbook_analyzer

Comment: Once you unpackage, what file is so large? Is it one of the TWB files? TWB files are usually not too large, but can have large images included in the XML (represented as UUENCODED text) Say from a shape palette or thumbnails - but hard to believe that a TWB file would increase by 50MB just to store some thumbnail images

Comment: Yes, it is the TWB file.

Comment: The TWB file is in XML (text) format. Somewhat human readable. You can view it with a text editor like Notepad++ or Sublime. If you change the suffix to XML, many editors will format/color code it to make reading easier. Then look to see what is taking so much space. You might see large walls of text characters - that is embedded binary data encoded as text. Look at the XML tags around those to get an idea about what they are. You probably are embedding some very large images or such somehow, maybe embedded shape files or embedded geocoding files or embedded images or thumbnails.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the insight I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you several ideas to reduce the file size or perform analyses on large files:

1. Check Extracts:

Tableau workbooks often use data extracts to improve performance. Check if there are any large extracts embedded in the workbook. If so, you might consider optimizing or reducing the data included in the extracts.

2. Evaluate Data Source Connections:

Verify that they are pointing to the expected data sources and that there are no unnecessary connections that might be contributing to the file size.

3. Evaluate Data Blending:

If you're using data blending, ensure that it's set up efficiently. Sometimes, inefficient blending can result in larger file sizes.

4. Unused Sheets or Dashboards:

Check for unused sheets or dashboards in the workbook. Deleting any unnecessary elements can help reduce the file size.

5. Evaluate Calculated Fields and Formulas:

Complex calculations and formulas can contribute to file size. Review calculated fields and formulas to ensure they are necessary and optimized.

6. Review Images and Backgrounds:

Large images or background images can increase file size. If there are images used in the workbook, consider optimizing or compressing them.

7. Optimize Data Types:

Ensure that data types are optimized for storage efficiency. For example, using integer data types instead of float for whole numbers can reduce file size.

8. Remove Unused Data Sources:

If you have unused or redundant data sources, remove them from the workbook to reduce unnecessary data storage.

9. Analyze Workbook XML:

Tableau workbooks are essentially XML files. You can manually inspect the workbook XML to identify any unexpected elements or large sections of data that might be contributing to the file size.

10. Consider Performance Recording to identify bottlenecks

Help > Settings and Performance > Start Performance Recording

Answer (score 0):

The TWB file is in XML (text) format. Somewhat human readable. You can view it with a text editor like Notepad++ or Sublime. If you change the suffix to XML, many editors will format/color code it to make reading easier.

Then look to see what is taking so much space. You might see large walls of text characters - that is embedded binary data encoded as text. Look at the XML tags around those to get an idea about what they are.

You probably are embedding some very large images or such somehow, maybe embedded shape files or embedded geocoding files or embedded images or thumbnails.